# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException

Tags: java, android, inflate-exception

This project runs a splash screen then goesto the main activity. As of right now it crashes after the splash screen. I cannot find where it is having trouble starting the MainActivity. When I try to run the project I receive the following message:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnIrishDance, btnIrishFolk;
    MediaPlayer mpIrishDance, mpIrishFolk;
    int playing;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnIrishDance = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnIrishDance);
        btnIrishFolk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnIrishFolk);

        btnIrishDance.setOnClickListener(bIrishDance);
        btnIrishFolk.setOnClickListener(bIrishFolk);

        mpIrishDance = new MediaPlayer();
        mpIrishDance = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.irishdance);

        mpIrishFolk = new MediaPlayer();
        mpIrishFolk = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.flute);

        playing = 0;
    }

    Button.OnClickListener bIrishDance = new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (playing){
                case 0:
                    mpIrishDance.start();
                    playing = 1;
                    btnIrishDance.setText("Pause Irish Dance");
                    btnIrishFolk.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mpIrishDance.pause();
                    playing = 0;
                    btnIrishDance.setText("Play Irish Dance");
                    btnIrishFolk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    Button.OnClickListener bIrishFolk = new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (playing){
                case 0:
                    mpIrishFolk.start();
                    playing = 1;
                    btnIrishFolk.setText("Pause Irish Dance");
                    btnIrishDance.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mpIrishFolk.pause();
                    playing = 0;
                    btnIrishFolk.setText("Play Irish Dance");
                    btnIrishDance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Splash Screen

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

/**Called when activity is first created**/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            finish();

            //this should open mainActivity
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    };

    Timer opening = new Timer();
    opening.schedule(task, 5000);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_splash_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/irishdance"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/song1_button_text"
        android:id="@+id/btnIrishDance"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/irishfolk"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnIrishFolk"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/song2_button_text"
        android:id="@+id/btnIrishFolk"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnIrishDance"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnIrishDance" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_splash_screen.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mypackage.nkhproj5.SplashScreen">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/splashscreenImage"
        android:src="@drawable/splashknot"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat output:

```
10-27 09:41:28.748    3800-3800/edu.rwu.comsc450.nhallock.nkhproj5 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mypackage.nkhproj5, PID: 3800
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage.nkhproj5.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 82944012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 26MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at edu.rwu.comsc450.nhallock.nkhproj5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-27 09:41:31.078    3800-3800/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3800 SIG: 9
```

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 82944012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 26MB until OOM*

Comment: @Blackbelt i used 'android:largeheap="true"  to allocate more memory but it continues crashing

Comment: *i used 'android:largeheap="true" to allocate more memory but it continues crashing*. `'android:largeheap="true"` is never the solution.

Comment: You are attempting to allocate ~80MB of heap space, apparently for one of your `ImageView` widgets. This is **absolutely huge**, the equivalent of a 4553px by 4553px image. No Android device has a screen that size. Find what image this is (my guess would be `splashknot`) and reduce the size of the image by a factor of 50 or so.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you! it turns out I was using an hd image that was far too large in my MainActivity